# nginx remove php extension after keep redirecting to diretory even has same name of php files

Tags: php, nginx

my default server config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    } 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

my root folder likes

> var/www/html
>
> - service.php
> - service (diretory)
> - ㄴ index.php

when i connect with http://example/service here 
just redirect to service/index.php not service.php 
what i did wrong ??
i want use both of them

```
http://www.exmaple/service  -> service.php
```

and

```
http://www.example/service/  -> service/index.php
```

i'm using ubuntu 20.04 nginx 1.18.0 php 8.1

Answer (score 0):

In `try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;`, the `$uri/` term tests if `service` is a directory *before* you branch to `@extensionless-php` to rewrite the URI to `service.php`. You could just remove that term from the `try_files` statement, as long as that doesn't break another part of your website.